# How to display the value of a Perl variable in a tooltip

Tags: perl, hover, cgi, tooltip

I've got a CGI perl script which processes a large Application Configuration file and displays extracted config data in table format.

One of the columns shows the hostname for a given server extracted from the config file.

What I'd like to do is have the alias name displayed (stored in `$alias`) when the user hovers over the hostname - much like a tooltip.

Each table row will have a different hostname and alias and I'm creating the table by iterating through an array.

I'm using the object-oriented approach to CGI Perl.

I tried the using the following:

```
print $cgi->start_td({class=>'primpeer',title=>'$aliasName'}),"$hostName";
```

but this just echoed the $aliasName in the tooltip rather than the contents of $aliasName

Comment: What does your code look like? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables inside single quote are not interpolled.
Just use double quote instead of single quote:

```
print $cgi->start_td({class=>'primpeer',title=>"$aliasName"}),"$hostName";  
                                        here __^   here __^
```

or without any quotes:

```
print $cgi->start_td({class=>'primpeer', title=>$aliasName}), $hostName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the value of your `$alias` into a [`title` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3) (presumably of a `td` element). It will produce a tooltip for you like the `alt` attribute of an `img` element.

Comment: That's what I tried but the tooltip just printed the string $aliasName rather than the contents of $aliasName

Comment: `print $cgi->start_td({class=>'primpeer',title=>'$aliasName'}),"$hostName";`

Comment: Change that to `title => $aliasName`. It is very rarely correct to put a variable name in quotes.